# When to trademark my game/game company

Tags: copyright, marketing, publishing, distribution, trademark

I'm planning on building an online presence of a game I'm working on once it reaches a stage that would allow for creating marketing material (screenshots, trailers, etc).

Should I trademark/copyright my game before I start building online presence?
How long does the trademarking/copyrighting process take?
How much money can it cost?

Comment: Is this game going to be paid? How do you plan to earn money? (if that's your target)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about game development.

Comment: @TomTsagk the game will be free to download but will contain microtransactions

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! This question appears to have been asked before. You may want to browse the tags to find more information about it.